# Simple sql query with 3 tables

Tags: mysql, postgresql-9.3

Consider the following database with 3 tables:
persons, cars, persons_cars (join table).
Each with the its fields described below:

```
persons: id, phone, address
cars: id, model, manufacturer
persons_cars: id, id_car, id_person
```

For current case consider all fields `varchar` expect the `id` (of course primary and foreign keys).

How would look like a query which returns me the `id` of the person who owns multiple cars (at least two) of the same manufacturer. (As manufacturer can be the same e.g. 'volkswagen', 'volvo', 'honda', etc.). Is it possible to do this in one query?

Comment: MySQL or PostgreSQL ? Please specify the exact RDBMS you are using.

Comment: And go on . Try something. Note also that the id column in the third table serves no purpose (unless (model,manufacturer) is unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple way to do this.  We can aggregate the `persons_cars` table by person, and then compare the total manufacturer count against the distinct manufacturer count.  If the former be larger than the latter, then we may assume that a duplicate manufacturer exists, i.e. that the person owns two or more cars from a single manufacturer.

```
SELECT pc.id_person
FROM persons_cars pc
INNER JOIN cars c
    ON pc.id_car = c.id
GROUP BY pc.id_person
HAVING COUNT(*) > COUNT(DISTINCT c.manufacturer);
```

You tagged with both MySQL and Postgres, though this answer should run on either database without any problems.

Comment: I did not think about this approach, but it is quite a good one. Thank you!